# alternative expression for belittlement

Tags: synonyms

I am German and currently writing my thesis in English. Currently trying to categorize my qualitative codes and I am looking for an alternative expression/word for belittlement, that is less negatively connotated. It should be descriptive of making a situation appear less harmful. Minimization is part of the category.

I would greatly appreciate your input and I am looking forward to your answers:)

Best,

Pia

Comment: If a person is doing something to reduce the harmfulness of a problem, their action is  **to mitigate** the risk or the harm/loss. This doesn’t sound quite right for the problem you described, but it may give you another class of words to think about.

Answer (score 1):

*Downplaying* would be making something seem less offensive or dangerous, without necessarily having negative connotations.

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for an alternative word / expression for "[belittlement](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20belittle)".

> make (someone or something) seem unimportant.

- With less negative connotation
- That can be used when making a situation appear less harmful.
- Minimization is part of the category

**Options**:
Not a complete list.

[Diminish](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20diminish)

> " - make or become less.
>   - make (someone or something) seem less impressive or valuable."

[Reduce](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20reduce)

> "2. Bring someone or something to (a lower or weaker state, condition, or role)."

[Downgrade](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20downgrade)

> "reduce to a lower grade, rank, or level of importance."

[Underrate](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20underrate)

> "underestimate the extent, value, or importance of (someone or something)"

[Underestimate](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20underestimate)

> "estimate (something) to be smaller or less important than it actually is"

Answer (score 0):

One more:

They are [making light of](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/make-light-of-something) the situation.

> **make light of something**
> to joke about something or treat it as not
>   being very serious, especially when it is important  She tried to make
>   light of the situation, but I could tell that she was worried.