# What is the apt word for an ironically brief/vulgar description of an entity by a highly educated, accomplished individual?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, a neurosurgeon describing an arterio-venous malformation as a “screwed-up circulation”, or a psychologist telling his patient “that’s your stuff...deal with it”.
Because the professionals are so accomplished, it’s within their providence to speak like this.
What’s a succinct word or phrase I’m looking for??

Comment: Hello, Bill. This is a single word request. It's not an exact match for [alternative expression for belittlement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497565/alternative-expression-for-belittlement),  or [confusion between 'disparage', 'belittle', 'denigrate', 'deprecate' and 'depreciate'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460025/confusion-between-disparage-belittle-denigrate-deprecate-and-depreciate), but I hope mere repeats of these answers aren't given. They don't mandate the 'by a highly educated, accomplished individual' requirement, which is what makes this _not_ a dupe.

Comment: Is it dumbing down?

Comment: It's a type of *bathos* but I don't imagine there's a word that fully meets your desires.

Comment: I don't think what you say is right. They are just using colloquial language. Although I doubt a psychologist would say that to a patient.

Comment: The irony being that this "dumbing down" is unnecessary, and/or because it is 'sardonic' given the context?

Comment: Sometimes this is a euphemism, but it can also be an attempt at sarcasm. They could use technical language, but colloquial language has more emotional content.